# It is possible to use iPhone as BT headset for the computer?

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to use my iPhone as an BT headset, is it possible to pair it with the computer and to have it used for computer calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively no, the iPhone is limited to what is parable to it, and the functions once it is paired.. With a jailbroken iPhone there may be some third party software out there.

Comment: Do you have some app names?

Comment: Not sure, but what ever it is, it would involve "BTStack" which is a custom BlueTooth driver written for the iPhone with less restrictions then the built in iPhone driver. See here for more information: http://code.google.com/p/btstack/